# Dialog Fragment onactivity result

Tags: android, dialog, android-fragments

my question is for Dialog Fragment being cshown from a activity, then on the dialog fragment we initiate the onactivityresult(..) the dialog is waiting for result from activity.

- when activity top one returns, the dialog fragment is not visible.
- the fragment is actually there, under the parent activity who originally showed the fragment.

wired case
in case the orientation were changed when fragment was displayed the flow works flawlessly.

this has only started to happen 4.2 on Nexus 7, any body can help so that the fragment still keeps visible and get the result back

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the google documentation on dialog fragments?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

I think the easiest way would be to create an interface for your dialog fragment,
then your caller activity would implement that interface.
Then you can show your dialog fragment by doing something like:

> MyDialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment();
>    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "fragment_new");

The documentation has plenty of examples.

Comment: let me explain my bits here

- support fragmentActivity A
-DialgFragment D
-valuePickerActivity V

D is shown from A
V is initiated from D

while on activityresult the D is no more visible (only in N7 4.1+)
works like a charm on any other device OS

for now i have a hack for initialing D through a empty content Activity EMPT from A solves the problem now but not sure whats happening here